# Intellij Run Configurations as root on linux

Tags: intellij-idea, gulp, root

I recently switched my dev station from Windows to a Linux machine, and I'm setting things up. I use Intellij for web development. On my Windows box, I had run configurations for things like `npm start`, and gulp lots of tasks. In Linux, most of these error out, because they require root to run. Is there a way to run commands in Intellij's run configuration as root? I'd prefer to not have to edit the gulp files, as they're shared over git with my team who runs Windows.

I have intellij-idea-ultimate version 2019.3.1 installed as a snap on Pop OS version 19.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to run IntelliJ IDEA itself via `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I've marked the correct answer above, but I wanted to make a couple of notes for anyone else dealing with the same issue. Instead of running intelliJ IDEA as root, I made some edits so that the commands I was running didn't have to run as root. I changed the port I was hosting on to a port above 1000, which doesn't require root. npm did not give my user ownership of folders it generated like those inside of `node_modules`. I used `chown` to change the ownership back to me.